# postgres averaging 3 columns into one

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a table that has name, date, time, price, size e.g.:

```
symb1 4-13-14 8:28:32:00  25.00 400
symb1 4-13-14 8:29:03:00  25.01 600
symb1 4-13-14 8:29:17:00  24.93 500
symb1 4-13-14 8:29:17:00  24.96 1400
symb1 4-13-14 8:30:22:00  25.02 800
```

I want to create a new table that will average each minute by price and value of order. So I want to have name, date, time(in minutes interval now) and average price per unit. So the following.:

```
symb1 4-13-14 8:28:00:00  25.00
symb1 4-13-14 8:29:00:00  24.966
symb1 4-13-14 8:30:00:00  25.02
```

Is there a way to do it in postgres or do I need to write a script(in python or something) that calls each date/time combination manually calculates it and then reinserts it?

Comment: Any code sample for this that you have already written would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your SQL:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('minute', timestamp_column_name) AS timestamp_minute,
  avg(price) AS avg_price
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY 1;
```

Of course, replace "timestamp_column_name" and "your_table" with the appropriate object names per your database.